# how variables are set when using multiple OR (||) operators in Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, operator-precedence

I'm having trouble understanding the order in which an `||` is executed in Jquery/Javascript.

If I have this:

```
  someVar = $el.attr("one") || options.two || "three";
```

it sets `someVar` to "three" when both `$el.attr("one")` and `options.two` are not defined.

I need to add another condition to this statement, like so:

```
  someVar = $el.attr("one") || options.two || options.extra == "true" ? undefined : "three";
```

So this should say:

**If neither `'$el.attr("one")'` or `'options.two'` are defined, check if `'options.extra == true'`, if it's true, set to `'undefined'`, otherwise set to `'three'`.**

However, I'm always getting `undefined` even if I set `$el.attr("one")` and I don't understand why?

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `options.extra == "true"` will only be true when `options.extra` is false or it is exactly the string `true`, which is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you must put some parenthesis:

```
someVar = $el.attr("one") || options.two || (options.extra == "true" ? undefined : "three");
```

in fact your own code is read as:

```
someVar = ($el.attr("one") || options.two || options.extra == "true") ? undefined : "three";
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `? :` has a weaker binding than `||` and therefore is evaluated last. This is the same as if you would write:

```
( $el.attr("one") || options.two || options.extra == "true" ) ? undefined : "three";
```

which always will yield undefined as the first expression always is true (because you set `$el.attr("one")`)

That's why you have to take parens to fix that:

```
$el.attr("one") || options.two || (options.extra == "true" ? undefined : "three");
```

Check the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), it comes in handy in such cases.

Comment: @frequent I added a link to the javascript operator precedence table, this is your best friend in such cases;)

Answer (score 0):

The way to write it with logic operators only is

```
  someVar = $el.attr("one") || options.two || options.extra != "true" && "three" || undefined;
```

...not that I would use that in actual code. (I probably wouldn't mix logic operators with the conditional operator either.)

Comment: should be `options.extra == "true" && undefined || "three"` because `&&` has higher precedence.

Comment: Fixed. Putting `"three"` at the end would not work since an OR chain with a truthy value is the end could never give a falsy value such as `undefined`.

Comment: That's true - that's why you should not use this for conditional variable assignment;)